# java, jquery and jsp messaging

Tags: java, jquery

I am using jquery get request to pass the array of strings to java class from jsp.

something like this :

```
 $.ajax({url: '<%= My java class %>'+'?s1='+ $("#networkBox1").val()+'&box1=Box1&tick=add&val1='+ allvs+'&s2='+ $("#networkBox2").val()+'&box2=Box2&val2='+ allvs,
                 type: 'get',
                 dataType: 'text',
                 async: false,
                 success: function(data) {Processbox(newdata);}});
```

allvs --is array of strings.

I am converting these strings to list in My java class and than updating the java collections (hashMap) on the basis of parameters `s1` and `s2` and getting the response back by jquery and printing again by Processbox function shown above. The parametrs s1 and s2 can be same for different users. so my question is do i need to have my methods in java class as thread safe (synchronized) ? This is a web app which will be used by different users when they login into website.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: please see above i asked question "do i need to have my methods in java class as thread safe (synchronized) ?"